# I am confused about the Javascript Client Object Model and when it can be used

Tags: javascript, web-services, client-object-model

Is it only intended for use "inside" SharePoint?

Using the .Net/C# client object model I can execute applications on my 
local machine and access a remote SharePoint server.

I can only find examples for the JavaScript object model that use it on the 
same server.

There is a limitation in JavaScript about the same origin policy, but
is that the only limitation of why JavaScript does not work remotly?

If so, what is the best way, from a Windows 8 RT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSOM provided by SharePoint is indeed intended to run only on SharePoint for custom solutions (or content editor web part content) within SharePoint.  The required authentication, context setup, and core JS is provided on SharePoint pages by SharePoint.

As far as using JavaScript against a remote SharePoint site, you'd have to access SharePoint's web services.  My answer to your other question should help with that: [Best way to access SharePoint (online) from a Windows 8 RT/Metro application?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61534/best-way-to-access-sharepoint-online-from-a-windows-8-rt-metro-application)