# Best way to access SharePoint (online) from a Windows 8 RT/Metro application?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, windows-8

I am developing a Windows 8 tile app/Metro (Windows RT) application. 
I have experienced some problems linking with the C# client object model
assemblies due to limitations in RT.

I was hoping I might use the JavaScript OM, but that does not appear to work
either.

Is the best approach to use REST without any helping libraries?
I have found authentication to be a challenge here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best route here is going to be to use web services from SharePoint in your Windows Store app.

You can do it in JavaScript apps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761502.aspx

Or in .NET apps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh761504(v=win.10).aspx

As for credentials, your user will need to enter them into your application so that you can use them when making the web requests.  You can use the credential vault thing that Windows has: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br229572.aspx

This article has a list of available web services for SharePoint Online: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147180.aspx